Buildozer fails to compile simple hello world app to apk
the code is quite simple
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
class ButtonApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text="Button")
ButtonApp().run()

But when I run:
buildozer --verbose android debug
I get this error message:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sh<3.0,>=2 (from versions: 0.106.linux-i686, 0.107, 0.108, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 1.10, 1.11, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.12.4, 1.12.5, 1.12.6, 1.12.7, 1.12.8, 1.12.9, 1.12.10, 1.12.11, 1.12.12, 1.12.13, 1.12.14, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sh<3.0,>=2


Welcome to SO. Please provide a minimal reproducible example to help others to reproduce the error and debug it.
You also haven't actually asked a question. Please update your post to add more details for reproducibility and actually ask a question.
